# Spring Boot - Configure two datasources

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I want to configure two data sources for my application. My application starts up fine and seems both of my repositories give expected response (from two Databases) when I write query directly above the JPA repository method as below.

```
@Repository
public interface DB2Repo extends JpaRepository<DB2Entity, Integer>{
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * from \"TABLE_1\"")
    List<DB2Entity> findAll();  
}
```

But, when I try to directly utilize the available JPA method like below:

```
@Repository
public interface DB2Repo extends JpaRepository<DB2Entity, Integer>{
}
```

and if I invoke the JPA method directly in my Controller as below:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/db2")
public class DB2Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    DB2Repo db2Repo;    

    @GetMapping("/getList")
    public List<DB2Entity> getMovies() {
        List<DB2Entity> res = db2Repo.findAll();
        return res;
    }
}
```

I get relation does not exist error as below:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "**dbo**.TABLE_1" does not exist
```

I see that it is automatically looking into **dbo** schema instead of **public** schema

*Below is my application.properties:*

```
spring.datasource2.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB1
spring.datasource2.username=//username
spring.datasource2.password=//pwd

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB2
spring.datasource.username=//usrname
spring.datasource.password=//pwd
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = dbo
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database=default
```

**Following is the DB1 Config class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories( entityManagerFactoryRef = "DB1EntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "DB1TransactionManager",    basePackages = {
    "com.datasource1.repository" } )
@EntityScan("com.datasource1.entity" )
public class Db1Config {
    
        @Primary
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
        public DataSourceProperties SourceProperties() {
            return new DataSourceProperties();
        }
        
        @Primary
        @Bean( name = "DB1Datasource" )
        @ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "spring.datasource.configuration" )
        public DataSource dataSource()
        {
            return SourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                    .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        }
        
        @Primary
        @Bean( name = "DB1EntityManagerFactory" )
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory( EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                @Qualifier( "DB1Datasource" ) DataSource dataSource )
        {
            return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.datasource1.entity")
                    .persistenceUnit("db1").build();
        }
        
        @Primary
        @Bean( name = "DB1TransactionManager" )
        public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
                @Qualifier( "DB1EntityManagerFactory" ) EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory )
        {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
        }
}
```

**Following is the DB2Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories( entityManagerFactoryRef = "DB2EntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "DB2TransactionManager",    basePackages = {
    "com.DB2.repository" } )
@EntityScan( "com.DB2.entity" )
public class Db2Config {
    
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource2")
        public DataSourceProperties DB2SourceProperties() {
            return new DataSourceProperties();
        }

        
        @Bean( name = "DB2Datasource" )
        @ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "spring.datasource2.configuration" )
        public DataSource dataSource()
        {
            return DB2SourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                    .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        }
        
        @Bean( name = "DB2EntityManagerFactory" )
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory( EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                @Qualifier( "DB2Datasource" ) DataSource dataSource )
        {
            return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.DB2.entity")
                    .persistenceUnit("db2").build();
        }
        
        @Bean( name = "DB2TransactionManager" )
        public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
                @Qualifier( "DB2EntityManagerFactory" ) EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory )
        {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
        }
}
```

**How do I resolve this?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post your entities? And using a repository directly in the `Controller` is not a good practice, try seperating the logic by using a `Service` between them, and why do you need a native query? The repo gives you out of the box Functions. If you really need native query, then use `"public"."TABLE_1"` as selector.

Comment: @Renis1235, Thanks for your suggestion. I found the error was due to this property spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = dbo. When I removed the property, it is working fine